# Is there a convention regarding when election manifestos are launched in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, election, parties

[The Independent](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/politics/general-election-2019-boris-johnson-tory-manifesto-labour-register-vote-a9176346.html) is claiming that both the Conservative and Labour parties will launch their election manifestos in the week beginning 18/11/19. Is this assertion based on some tradition or convention, or is it simply a matter of the practicalities of writing and publishing a manifestos for a snap election?

This question refers to both any convention, tradition or requirement on a national level, or one put in place by the parties themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is up to each individual party to decide when (or even if) they publish a manifestos.  Much of their policies will already be set in broad form, but they will need some time to refine them and put them into a general election manifesto.

In 2017, the three main parties all published their manifestos around three weeks before the election (Labour on 16 May, LibDems on 17 May, Conservatives 18 May).  This is a similar timeframe to what is being claimed by The Independent.